# Using reflection to enumerate through the fields of a struct at runtime

Tags: data-structures, rust

If I have a data structure like this:

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn setX(&mut self, x: i32) -> &mut Point {
        self.x = x;
        self
    }
}
```

Is it possible to iterate through `Point` and see both each member and the name of each member?

Is it also possible to go through the implementation and see what each function's name is?

Is it possible to do the above two tasks at runtime, without special implementations?

Comment: FYI what you're trying to do usually goes under the term "reflection".

Comment: @delnan Is there a better I could phrase my title / post?

Comment: I would just use `pub` struct fields. And perhaps a tuple struct.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is a way to (ab)use [`Encodable`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/trait.Encodable.html) or [`Serialize`](http://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde/ser/trait.Serialize.html) traits to obtain reflection-like information about structure contents (not methods, though).

`Encodable`/`Serialize` are used primarily for writing a structure to some serialized representation, e.g. a JSON object. Their implementations can be automatically generated (e.g. with `#[derive(RustcEncodable)]` for `Encodable`) for any structure whose contents also implement corresponding trait.

Implementations of these traits capture information about the structure and they pass it to an implementation of [`Encoder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/trait.Encoder.html) or [`Serializer`](http://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde/ser/trait.Serializer.html). Implementors of the latter traits usually use this information (field names, types and values) to serialize objects but of course you can write your own implementation of `Encoder`/`Serializer` which will do with this information whatever you want. I'm not providing an example of such implementation here because they tend to be boilerplate-y, but you can find some through the links above.

The limitation is that you always need a value of a structure in order to get information about fields. You can't just get a list of fields of an arbitrary type, like e.g. Java reflection allows. I *think* it is possible to write an internally unsafe implementation of `Encoder`/`Serializer` and a function like `fn type_info<T: Encodable>() -> TypeInfo` which collects information about a type by creating an uninitialized piece of memory of the corresponding type and running its `Encodable` methods, but I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: To clarify why Rust can't accomplish the same thing for methods: Rust does not have a virtual machine counter-part like Java or C#. It is only compiled to assembly, and doesn't have type information stored with objects when they're created.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish the first thing (iterating over the fields) with my crate [`fields-iter`](https://docs.rs/fields-iter):

```rust
#[derive(fields_iter::FieldsInspect)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

for (name, value) in fields_iter::FieldsIter::new(&point) {
    // Do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rust does not really support this kind of reflection at runtime, no.

In theory, you *might* be able to write a syntax extension that would let you generate some code that would do something like this, maybe...